# Not able to set CSS style of an element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

hi i have an unordered list with some list elements and i want to set a css style for highlighting the list element that has been selected i am trying this but it has no effect on the style

```
function SelectThis(ctrl) {
    var list = document.getElementById("myslidemenu").getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].style.color = "blue";
    }

    ctrl.style.color = 'white';
}
```

and my html looks like this

```
<div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu">
    <ul>
        <li onclick="SelectThis(this);"><a href="Dashboard.aspx">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li onclick="SelectThis(this);"><a href="Geofence.aspx">Geofence</a>
        </li>
        <li onclick="SelectThis(this);"><a href="Personnel.aspx">Personnel</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br style="clear: left" />
</div>
```

this div tag is inside another div tag, cant i somehow over-ride the inner div tag to cause changes to the selected li in the Ul

and my css is like this

```
.jqueryslidemenu ul li a:hover{
 background: black; /*tab link background during hover state*/
  color: Yellow;
  }

.jqueryslidemenu{
font: bold 12px Arial;
background: #414141;
width: 100%;
}

.jqueryslidemenu ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

/*Top level list items*/
.jqueryslidemenu ul li{
position: relative;
display: inline;
float: left;
}

/*Top level menu link items style*/
.jqueryslidemenu ul li a{
display: block;
background: #414141; /*background of tabs (default state)*/
color: white;
padding: 8px 10px;
border-right: 1px solid #778;
color: #2d2b2b;
text-decoration: none;
height: 1%;
}
```

Comment: FYI: i have put a debugger; in the javascript and the code seems to be working as expected but i dont know why the styles are not taking any effect.

Comment: What is wrong here http://jsfiddle.net/AV4ya/ ?

Comment: FYI: This is present in the master page and when i click on the list element its redirecting me to another page but the styles are getting set back to default..

Comment: on list element click for exmaple Dashboard click it redirect to dash bord? and if redirect than page is refresh?

Comment: YES @sangramparmar parmathe page is redirecting and also refreshing hence the style is getting lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change style of `<a>` element instead of `<li>`.
Style of `<li>` is updated but `<a>` has its own style which should be overridden with JS.

Comment: Yes. To clarify, `<a>` is one of the few elements that has a color by default. Most other elements have `color:inherit`, so in most cases, it wouldn't matter if you styled something or if you styled its parent. Only in this case does it matter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the background instead? [Like that?](http://jsfiddle.net/Ht7rA/)

I removed in the test the anchors so it doesn't produce 404 errors.

```
function SelectThis(ctrl) {                         
    var list = document.getElementById("myslidemenu").getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].style.background = 'blue';
    }

    ctrl.style.background = 'white';
}
```

Comment: Since You have removed the <a> tag its working as expected so i guess the style in the <a> tag is over riding the style of the <li> tag.

Comment: I modified the javascript to, instead of doing `list[i].style.color` I use `list[i].style.background`. Check that out in your project.

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying is not working because your page is refresh

for i.e. if you click link than browser will redirect you that link

so after click on page load you can check current page and find link in your menu and give css to that

put this script in your page

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var page = top.location.toString().split("/");
        alert(page[page.length - 1].toString());
        $('#myslidemenu li').css('color', 'blue');
        $('#myslidemenu').find('a[href="' + page[page.length - 1].toString() + '"]').closest('li').css('color', 'white');

    });
```

on document ready it takes page name and find anchor tag containing href= current page and change it's closest li color;

Comment: i added this code in my master page and it it dosent seem to have an effect i am new to jquery in the last line of your method you are finding the li element from the previous page right? dont i have to set the style of this newly found element?

Comment: in list line find anchor tag which has href attribute qeuals to current page ..than find closest li means it's parent li ..and give style to that li